# Delete an Entire Row/Column if row.names/col.names Contain Characters from row.names/col.names of another dataframe in R and Save

Tags: r

I have an **n x 1** `df_vector` vector as follow:

```
Var1:M1 2.5
Var1:M2 3.8
Var1:M3 NaN
Var1:M4 9.3
Var2:M1 0.1
Var2:M2 2.3
Var2:M3 8.8
Var2:M4 NaN
```

Then I have an **n x n** `df_matrix` matrix:

```
        Var1:M2 Var1:M3 Var1:M4 Var2:M1 Var2:M2 Var2:M3 Var2:M4
Var1:M1 46900   788888  700000  490603  479063  6468000 649111
Var1:M2 52823   543189  431863  134696  413000  4980000 550690
Var1:M3 34343   543199  543169  413000  479006  4689703 567000
Var1:M4 56655   745893  134000  130000  463090  9806300 790643
Var2:M1 87676   413596  156000  546970  310000  9730000 700000
Var2:M2 67786   124397  134680  546300  146900  1312600 669000
Var2:M3 45332   417933  203333  131588  137900  4690530 978000
Var2:M4 32422   660796  314796  786000  479000  7690000 796080
```

What I want to do is: if a row in `df_vector` has `NaN` value then use its row.name and search for it in df_matrix and delete any row and/or column entirely that has the same name as that row.name for which there is NaN value in df_vector. BUT at the same time save those deleted columns/rows to a new dataframe in the same order. Therefore, in this particular example, in df_vector Var1:M3 and Var2:M4 have NaN values, so from df_matrix rows that have the name Var1:M3 and Var2:M4 should be entirely deleted, and columns that have the name Var1:M3 and Var2:M4 should also be entirely deleted. And these deleted rows and columns should make a new dataframe in the same format as df_matrix.

What is the best way to achieve this? Since my original dataset is 10,000 x 10,000 matrix, when I tried to write if and for, but it was extremely slow and took a very very long time to compile.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you add the code you tried, even though it is slow. The generally expected format for questions is that you show what you tried in addition to describing the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be faster to avoid looping. The easiest way would be to do this in two steps.

```
# remove rows and then remove columns
df_matrix[is.nan(df_vector[,1]),] <- NULL
df_matrix <- df_matrix[,!is.nan(df_vector[,1])]
```

The above code may not work as expected if the column names and row names don't exactly match the order in the two data frames. If that is the case then get the row names from df_vector and use %in% to keep those specific rows and columns. For the 2nd part of keeping the deleted data it's not clear what you want since it will basically be a copy of the existing df_matrix with a bunch of irrelevant rows and columns. What values do you want in the extra filler cells?

Comment: This worked great. I tried `df_matrix <- df_matrix[,!is.nan(df_vector[,1])]` and `df_matrix <- df_matrix[!is.nan(df_vector[,1]),]`. This deleted the rows and columns that I wanted. By the 2nd part of my question, I meant that I want to create a new dataframe/matrix out of these values that conform to the condition above, i.e. make a new dataframe `newdf` out of the rows/columns that get deleted from df_matrix.